# What is the problem with this onload event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, html

I have this password field

```
input class="txtfld" type="password" id="TextBoxLoginPassword"  runat="server" 
                value="password"     
                onfocus="javascript:if(this.value == 'password') this.value='';" 
                onblur="javascript:if(this.value == '') this.value='password';" 
                onload="javascript:if(this.value == '') this.value='password';"
                validationgroup="Login" />
```

Problem is that this appears as empty. Even I have set a default value. 
To solve this problem I have added an onload event and I get following error

1. Empty Character Literal
2. Too many Characters in character literals
   Why does this appear empty in first place and why do I get these errors? What I need is to show a default value in password field.

Comment: Default fields are always for informing the user about the input. Why do you want a default field for password that will be shown as dots?

Comment: @Amitabh How? 
@Rahul Ihave only username and password fields. username is informing that enter username here. so an empty password field does not very good with that. and whenever user will see dots  he will understand it is for password. I dont have any labels associated with these feilds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the combination of the text in the OnLoad and the `runat=server`.

Because of that runat attribute, asp.net thinks the OnLoad specifies a server-side function. And then `''` and `'password'` seem (at least to C#) to specify character literals, of which the first has too few actual characters ("Empty Character Literal") and the second too many.

So try to remove the "runat=server" (and read the password directly from the QueryString)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you want to provide a "watermark", not the real password. Have you looked at the  [Watermark extender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx) of the Ajax control toolkit?

Comment: Actually, the term is [placeholder](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute), as included in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: Even displaying dots should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

@Hans Kesting answer is correct, but if you don't want to use extender, you can use the following code.

```
<input class="txtfld" type="text" id="TextBoxLoginPassword"   
                value="enter password"     
                onfocus="javascript:if(this.type != 'password') this.value='';this.type='password'" 
                 />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really sweet bit of JQuery / CSS that you could use here and elsewhere in your site to solve your problem:

http://attardi.org/labels/#demo